# How to call unique function for dynamically created checkboxes in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to dynamically create a set of check-boxes that each call a function differently when clicked

```
function initAllButtons(variable, length)
{
   for(c = 0; c < length; c++)
   {
      clicks.push(true);
   }


   for(i = 0; i < length; ++i)
   {
      var label = document.createElement("label");
      var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
      checkbox.type = "checkbox";
      checkbox.checked = true;
      checkbox.value = btns[i];
      checkbox.class = "colorCoder";
      label.appendChild(checkbox);

      document.getElementById('Buttons').appendChild(checkbox);

      $('#Buttons').on('click', function(){updateData(i,clicks);});
   }
}
```

Btns is just an array of strings. I really want to call the UpdateData function (which I have tested and works like it should) with the value or index of the button pressed, but nothing seems to be working.

This version just calls updateData ten times with index = 10. It obviously is not looking at the buttons as individual things. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check for javascript closures, you need to save the value of `i`for the listener

Comment: `('#Buttons').on('click', function(){updateData(i,clicks);});` doesn't make a lot of sense. You are binding multiple event handlers to the same element. Is that really what you want?

Comment: your `i` will always be equal to `length`. Don't set click events in loop like that.

Answer (score 0):

When dynamically adding elements to the dom, attaching event listeners gets tricky. This is a perfect use case for delegate on a parent container:

```
        var clickcontainer = document.getElementById('clickcontainer');

        clickcontainer.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
            e.stopPropagation();
        }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use closures to get this behavior, the closure function will create a new isolated scope and store the state of the variables.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

```
function clickClosure(i, clicks){
        return function(){
            updateData(i,clicks);
        }
    }

    function initAllButtons(variable, length)
    {
       for(c = 0; c < length; c++)
       {
          clicks.push(true);
       }


       for(i = 0; i < length; ++i)
       {
          var label = document.createElement("label");
          var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
          checkbox.type = "checkbox";
          checkbox.checked = true;
          checkbox.value = btns[i];
          checkbox.class = "colorCoder";
          label.appendChild(checkbox);

          document.getElementById('Buttons').appendChild(checkbox);

          var clickFnct = clickClosure(i, clicks);

          $('#Buttons').on('click', clickFnct);
       }
    }
```

Comment: That just calls all of the buttons once on is clicked. This is the same problem I have been having.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are doing nothing in your click handler to reference the clicked element.  To do that you need to specify selector as parameter to `on()`.  That might look like this:

```
$('#Buttons').on('click', ':checkbox', function() {
    // determine index of clicked item
    var index = $('#Buttons :checkbox').index(this);
    // call your function
    updateData(index,clicks);
}
```

You should also place this code after your loop as you only need to execute this line of code once.

Comment: That solved my problem. I didn't realize that you could reference an item in a div by index. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AstridK Glad to help.  If answer on SO solves your problem, you should select it as the as the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

Guessing by the code you are actually attaching a click event on a button rather than on the checkbox itself. Once you've created the element with `document.createElement` you can create your jQuery object and use the event handlers jQuery got.

```
var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
$(checkbox).on('click' function(){
    //Code here
}
```

If you want to keep the value of i you must use a closure. Look at my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/u13Le70g/

Comment: This won;t work since checkboxes are dynamically created.  You would need to attach `on('click')` handler to an ancestor element that exists in the DOM when binding is first made.