# How to insert function inside multiple markers created in a cycle

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to insert in a google Map,multiple markers,adding them into the map with a cycle;the problem is that I have a function inside the `infoWindow()` of the marker,but if I try with just two locations,the function is called in both markers,but only with the last value,in other words,the function takes just the last parameters.Here's the code

```
var luoghi = {"city":[
    { "lat":"45.46" , "lng":"9.19" , "name":"Milano" },
    { "lat":"41.12" , "lng":"16.86" , "name":"Bari" }
]} ; 

var marker2,i;          
    for( i in luoghi.city){
        lat = luoghi.city[i].lat;
        lng= luoghi.city[i].lng;
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

        marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title: ''+myLatlng
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker2,'click',(function(marker2){
            return function(){
                if(infoWindow) infoWindow.close();
                var contentString = '<p>Visiona meteo e foto utenti flickr in questa zona</p>'+
                                    '<input type= "button" value="Visualizza" onclick="visualizza()">';
                infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString
                });
                infoWindow.open(map,marker2);
        }
    })(marker2));
}
```

The function *visualizza()* is correct,the problem is in the cycle,I can't figure out why it does not work as I expect. Thanks in advance !

Comment: You need to use closures check this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941294/how-to-call-unique-function-for-dynamically-created-checkboxes-in-a-div/30941571#30941571

Comment: Can you please write me how to do in order to make this code run in the correct way? I'm not able to solve it @tao

Answer (score 0):

You have a scope problem. Try this :

```
var luoghi = {"city":[
    { "lat":"45.46" , "lng":"9.19" , "name":"Milano" },
    { "lat":"41.12" , "lng":"16.86" , "name":"Bari" }
]} ;

var marker = {};
var infoWindow = {};

for(var i in luoghi.city){
    var lat = luoghi.city[i].lat;
    var lng= luoghi.city[i].lng;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

    marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: ''+myLatlng
    });

   infoWindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<p>Visiona meteo e foto utenti flickr in questa zona</p><input type= "button" value="Visualizza" onclick="visualizza()">'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', function(marker){
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    }(marker[i]));
}
```

Comment: In this way the code does not work,it puts on the map just one marker(Milano) and it does not popup the infoWindow @Thibault